# Clipboard.js script works in view file but not in seperate .js file

Tags: javascript, yii2, clipboard

I am using clipboard.js to allow users to copy snippets of code from an API docs page.

```
<script> var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copyButton');</script>
```

When I run this script in my view the functionality all works as it should. However if i place the script in its own js file I get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Clipboard is not defined
```

I am using Yii2 framework so i am using assets to register sources like so:

```
 public $js = [
    "js/api.js",
];
```

And then I am registering that Asset inside of my main layout like so:

```
use metis\assets\ApiAsset;
ApiAsset::register($this);
```

Anyone got any ideas why?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you integrate it within a seperate file? Make sure that your import is done before you access the object in your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like either the Clipboard object isn't being initialized in time, or the clipboard.js file is registered after the script that is using it.  Can you verify from the client source that the clipboard.js file is defined before the script that is using it?

Comment: Thank you, apprentice(noob) error. The api.js file was being loaded before the clipboard file.